# how can i leave a space between these two objects

Tags: css

"justify-content: space-between;" I want to leave a space with but it doesn't work.

```css
.phone-back{flex-basis: 400px;flex-shrink: 0;height: 80vh;margin: auto;margin-top: auto;background-image: url(images1.jpg);background-size: cover;border-radius: 35px;}
.phone{display: flex;padding: 0;flex-direction: column;justify-content: space-between;}

.phone-top{list-style-type: none;margin-bottom: auto;background-color: white; border-radius: 35px 35px 0px 0px;}

.phone-bottom{list-style-type: none;margin-bottom: auto;background-color: white;border-radius: 0px 0px 35px 35px;}
```

```html
 <div class="phone-back">
                <ul class="phone">
                    <li class="phone-top">top</li>
                    <li class="phone-bottom">bottom</li>

                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have given it the property of `flex-direction:column;`
when you change the flex-direction Justify content and align items switch places in short.

apply `align-items: space-between;` instead of `justify-content:space-between;`

This should solve your problem and I hope you understand the concept as well!

Comment: dude i already did that, i know that concept but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `height` property to `.phone` because:

> The items are evenly distributed within the alignment container along the main axis.
> [MDN - justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

```css
.phone{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="phone">
    <li class="phone-top">top</li>
    <li class="phone-bottom">bottom</li>
</ul>
```